# How to send AD-groups from specific location in AD as role claims in ADFS

Tags: claims-based-identity, adfs, claims

I want my ADFS 2012 R2 to send group-membership from a specific location in Active Directory, how can I do this?

I tried "Send LDAP attributes as claims", Token-Groups - Unqualified Names => Group, but that gives me every group the user is a member of. I only want the groups located in a certain path in AD (for example org/department/applications/demoapplication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOTB, you can't do this.

However, you can write your own [custom attribute store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895358.aspx) where you can access AD directly using the .NET AD API's and get the group memberships you want.

Also, refer [How to create a Custom Attribute Store for Active Directory Federation Services 3.0](http://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2013/12/27/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0.aspx).

Comment: I think it might be possible using a custom claim transformation rule only? See this link: [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/05/07/ad-fs-2-0-claims-rule-language-part-2.aspx) I didn't try this myself, but I guess you could first get a list of all group-memberships including the path in AD, and then filter it using regular expressions.

Comment: Yup - you can using "memberOf" - I actually blogged about this - http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/adfs-problem-with-token.html ! You can't with "Send LDAP attributes as claims"